# PySpark: Replace values of dataframe based on criteria

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a dataframe as show below

```
+++++++++++++++++++++
colA | colB | colC |
+++++++++++++++++++++
123  | 3 | 0|
222  | 0 | 1|
200  | 0 | 2|
```

I want to replace the values in `colB` and `colC` with a value of 1 if they are greater than 0.

I am able to use the na.fill function if I need to fill nulls with 0. But I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your dataframe is df, then you can do the following:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when  

df = df.select('colA', 
                   when(df.colB > 0, 1).alias('colB'),
                   when(df.colB > 0, 1).alias('colC'))
```

This checks whether colB and colC are greater than 0 and assign 1.

Comment: Thanks. This was what I was looking for.

Comment: Good! If you could accept the answer that would be great!

Comment: Do we have to import some library for using 'when'?

Comment: Only functions: `from pyspark.sql.functions import when`